# How to get rid of image tearing d3d11?

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct3d11

If I open my app in full screen, I get severe tears. In other games, even with vcync turned off, this is almost invisible. How can I achieve the same effect without vsync? [cube example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edd84.jpg)

```
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 scd = {};
    if (mIsGame)
    {
        scd.Width = RECT_WIDTH(mRect_Game);
        scd.Height = RECT_HEIGHT(mRect_Game);
    }
    else
    {
        scd.Width = RECT_WIDTH(mRect_Editor);
        scd.Height = RECT_HEIGHT(mRect_Editor);
    }
    scd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scd.BufferCount = 1;
    if (mIsGame)
        scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

    FOG_TRACE(dxgiFactory2->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(mDevice, mHwnd, &scd, 0, 0, &mSwapChain1));
    FOG_TRACE(mSwapChain1->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mSwapChain)));
    dxgiFactory2->Release();

    if (mIsGame)
    {
        FOG_TRACE(mSwapChain1->SetFullscreenState(true, 0));
        mFullScreen = true;
    }
```

Comment: It usually depends on how your swapchain is declared and used. Please post some interesting code.

Comment: Without details on your DXGI SwapChain setup, we can't help you figure out the problem. See [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for a bunch of example device & swapchain set ups.

Comment: I added, take a look

Comment: if you set the swap effect to one of the flip model options you won't have any tearing at all even if you disabled vsync. The downside is that the flip model is added since Windows 8, so it probably won't work if you're planning to support Windows 7